# Run a Prometheus query without running the server

Tags: monitor, prometheus

I configured Prometheus to monitor some part of our system. There is a Data folder which (I think) all samples are stored in.

I run the Prometheus server and execute queries with the REST API whenever I need to analyse old data.

Is there any way to run queries (for example with command line) without running the Prometheus server itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to run the Prometheus server to perform queries. Make sure you've set a high retention time so that the old data isn't deleted.

Comment: Dear Brian, Is it possible to request for new feature?